# How do i get the user to input a value in Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to prompt the user to input a value for an age of a student. When ran it will return all students with this age.

```py
def find():
    mydb = myclient["DW1"]
    docs = mydb["student"]
    age = input("Enter Age: ")
    query = {"student.age": age}
    students = docs.find(query) 
    for stu in students:
        print(stu)
```

The prompt appears and user can input a value but unfortunately nothing occurs. When I change age in query to let say 19, I get the correct results but when I change to age and input 19 prompt nothing appears

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` function returns a value whose type is `str`. so, if the type of age is `int`, the age in query should be `int`, otherwise, it should be `str`.